# EntityManager connection

Tags: eclipselink, entitymanager

I am new to java. I have created my own development framework for dealing with entities depending on EntityManager. My problem is I want to get the sql connection reference used by EntityManager instance to execute additional database DML operations such that these operations should be committed or rolled back whenever the EntityManager is committed or rolled back.

Regards;

Answer (score 0):

To get the `java.sql.Connection` object for the EntityManager `em` use

```
Connection conn = em.unwrap(Connection.class);
```

This will work in EclipseLink, but not in Hibernate.

Comment: Thank you coladict for your response; I am already using the above code to get the connection reference but I am not sure if the connection is the same as that used by em or it is a new one.

Comment: Well, it does, if your entity manager is in a transaction. http://git.eclipse.org/c/eclipselink/eclipselink.runtime.git/tree/jpa/org.eclipse.persistence.jpa/src/org/eclipse/persistence/internal/jpa/EntityManagerImpl.java#n2919